# appending a tag is not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've applied the following jquery but could not get worked.

```
var medialink = $('<a>',{
class: 'all-videos-link',
href: 'index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=78'
});
$('#custom-module .moduletable').eq(2).find('h3').append(medialink);
```

In all browser it's working but not in IE. I tested in ie8. So I tried this

```
$('#custom-module .moduletable').eq(2).find('h3').css({background:'red'}); // and it's working
```

So, why append is not working for ie only.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error.....

Comment: Providing fiddle may better

Comment: Is IE in compatibility mode?

Comment: You need to quote `class`, it's a [reserved word in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). This may, or may not, be your problem; but unquoted is *expect* it to always generate errors.

Comment: nope, it's not in compatibility mode

Comment: If you are using the latest version of jQuery, you need to keep jQuery 1.x for ie8 : http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I'm using jquery from google cdn so it's latest version....

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks. I tested by quoting it and its working nice...

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, since it seemed to solve your problem. Accepting isn't compulsory, but if your problem is, indeed, solved by that comment/answer, please do consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the property-name `class`, as it's a reserved word, in the case of `class` a  'future keyword,' in JavaScript. Therefore, you should use:

```
var medialink = $('<a>',{
    'class': 'all-videos-link',
    href: 'index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=78'
});
```

Though I find it easier to simply quote *all* property-names of an object, since it reduces the need to remember which ones *must* be quoted (and under which implementation of ECMAScript they must be quoted), to give:

```
var medialink = $('<a>',{
    'class': 'all-videos-link',
    'href': 'index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=78'
});
```

References:

- [JavaScript's 'reserved-words' (at MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using jQuery 2.0.0 which doesnt support IE8. Try getting an older version such as 1.9.

Comment: Probably, it should have been a comment.

Comment: Why? This is a perfectly viable answer. They're asking why it doesn't working in IE8 and I've derived a logical answered based upon the information they have given me.

Comment: so, what should I do to accomplish newest version and old version of jquery >>>

Comment: Use version 1.9 or conditionally load the jquery based upon the clients browser.

Comment: @C-Link Just try to run your code on jsfiddle.net with some older versions of jquery. If any version runs your code as expected then just go with it.

Comment: Sure have a look here http://www.impressivewebs.com/loading-different-jquery-version-ie6-8/

Is there a particular reason you need version 2?